# Why is my Android fetching http://xtra3.gpsonextra.net/xtra.bin upon start?

Tags: gps, data-monitoring

I notice my HTC Desire fetches http://xtra3.gpsonextra.net/xtra.bin when it boots (and before I enter the PIN).

What is that ?

Here's the HTTP Request sent:

```
GET /xtra.bin HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*, application/vnd.wap.mms-message, application/vnd.wap.sic
x-wap-profile: http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/profiles/UAPROF/ccppschema-20021212#
Host: xtra3.gpsonextra.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Android
```

Comment: I just noticed today that gpsonextra.net resolves to https://www.qualcomm.cn/ , when requested via a web browser. Strange.

Comment: Not strange at all: GpsOneXtra is Qualcomm's implementation of using aGPS.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is done by **[gpsd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gpsd)**. The XTRA files are the current [GPS Almanac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_signals#Almanac). The location of where to download the XTRA files to is defined in [`/system/etc/gps.conf`](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=727887).

These files contain data that speed up the GPS, which will result in faster GPS position fixes.

Comment: I noticed my moto e is making this request, but i dont know if my data provider has blocked this dns and the request is not been resolved. Since i can only wireshark while the device is connected to wifi, i'm not able to make a tcp dump or something like that while the device is on mobile network to know if the request is getting unresolved. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have any idea whats going on? in my case.

Comment: I Post a question [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/126464/gps-is-not-getting-fix-signal)