# GPS is not getting fix signal

Tags: gps, mobile-network, location-services

I have a couple devices (Moto e XT1021, Moto e 2nd gen). Suddenly the app running on these devices stopped working, due the device stop receiving gps changes updates.

I did some research and tests, and i realize the problem is probably the network provider. For some reason the request made by [gpsd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gpsd) process to http://xtra2.gpsonextra.net/xtra2.bin is not getting resolved, as consequence the device takes to much time(more than 15 minutes in some cases) to get GPS fix and not receive updates as expected.

Here is how i did my tests.

1. Put disconnect wifi, use mobile data only
2. Put device on **Only device**, Go to Settings > Location > Mode.
3. Open any gps status app, check if is receiving gps updates.

The thing here is when the mobile data is connected, the gps status app stop receiving gps updates and satellite signals disappears, So i decided to put the device on airplane mode, then automatically the gps status app start receiving satellite signals and of course gps updates.

This weird thing made me thing the network has something to be here. So i decided to use other sim cards from other networks. And i realize the same configurations is working good, All devices start getting gps updates very fast.

So i went further and made a tcpdump on the device with every sim card, and i realize the the request to http://xtra2.gpsonextra.net/xtra2.bin are not resolved or getting response.

All this story is to know if someone else knows something about or if the network provider can block requests to xtra2.gpsonextra.net.